# Cannot swap Weth to Eth or anything

Tags: meta-transactions

I cannot swap Weth to anything. I have my wallet address and I used that same address on CTNFT to buy a token. Now I cannot link that same wallet and perform the swap.

Comment: Which blockchain are you using? Do you have the native coin to pay the transaction fees?